# How to use Flash Builder to debug swf which is generated by command line mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash, mxmlc

I use command line to make swf from flex project.

```
mxmlc -debug=true src\Main.mxml -output bin-debug\Main.swf
```

I can use `fdb` to debug the generated Main.swf, but how to use Flash Builder to debug it?

The reason I donot use Flash Builder to build swf is that Flash Builder crashes ever now and then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an external debugger for debugging.A good one is Monster Debugger which is easy yo use and has many options to debugg your swf file.